# Checking closeness of a mixture weibull and a mixture normal distribution to sample data

Tags: goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption, mixture-distribution, weibull-distribution, anderson-darling-test

I have a sample data whose histogram shows a two peak distribution. So I generated two distributions which is the Mixture (average) of two
(1) two weibull distributions
(2) two normal distributions

I would like to check which of the two distributions is closer to my sample data.

Is the anderson-darling test sufficient enough?

Answer (score 0):

"Which is closer" is not a testing situation.

You can use some goodness of fit statistics as a measure of closeness. In the case where the number of parameters is the same for the two fits, it would make sense to compare those measures.

You could just use the ordinary statistic as if the distribution had been completely specified ... as there's no calculation of a p-value there's no issue with that (even though you're estimating parameters) -- the statistic is telling you about how close (in a particular sense) the fit is.